# Android Out of memory exception while downloading multiple images(>2mb each) from server

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory

Here is my code and i get an outofMemory exception while downloading multiple images. I hv gone through a duplicate question but did not find a suitable reply.

```
try {
  HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet("http://staging.xyz.com/db/demo_img/abc.png");
  HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
  HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpRequest);
  HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
  BufferedHttpEntity bufferedHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
  InputStream is = bufferedHttpEntity.getContent();
  //Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "");
  //or bitmap
  //photos = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
  BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
  o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
  BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is,null,o);
  //The new size we want to scale to
  final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
  //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
  int scale=1;
  while(o.outWidth/scale/2>=REQUIRED_SIZE && o.outHeight/scale/2>=REQUIRED_SIZE)
   scale*=2;
  //Decode with inSampleSize
  BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
  o2.inSampleSize=scale;
  Bitmap photos= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, o2);

} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
  System.out.println("photo error1111");
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
  System.out.println("photo error1111");
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that you do not recycle the bitmap. Could that the the source of your problems?

Comment: I am downloading multiple images at once , so how wud i recycle the bitmaps before setting them to imageviews...????

Comment: Do you have a number of threads - each one downloading an image, scaling and then setting it using http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable) ?

Comment: No. i have a single Asynctask within which i am downloading the images. Got an error-----
"The application may be doing too much work on its main thread."

Comment: Oh. I understand now. I thought you were downloading many images in parallel and saving them to sdcard first and displaying them after the whole download has been completed..

Comment: If you use an AsyncTask for downloading, then you should not be getting this error ..

Comment: You could download and save the images to the filesystem first, resize them and then display them in your UI. It might save you some memory. I am pretty sure that you set options before opening an image which limit the size of the image in memory. Downloading and conversion should be done using an AsyncTask to avoid the system complaining about doing too much work on its main thread. Setting of the images should be done on the UI thread (AFAIK).

Answer (score 0):

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        photos.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, bytes);
```

just add this it will save ur memory

or simply try this:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize=2;                             CameraAndFolderActivity.myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(info.aImagePath, options);
```

Comment: bytes means another output stream. how will this serve my purpose. can u just give ur own version of the nest few lines of code?

Answer (score -1):

use the garbage collector..

```
System.gc();
```